# How to deal with the new status after a promotion?

Tags: leadership, teamleader

I recently was promoted to tech lead. Right now, all my SW co-workers are under my supervision and they have to follow the design and rules that I propose (obviously with some space for improvement with their inputs). I recently had a discussion with one of my workmates about a code that could be removed as it's not doing anything and we are not planning to use it at all, and he did not want to do it as he was thinking that in the future it could be used. This led to some arguments and in the end, he agreed to remove it, but it was quite difficult to convince him.

I am looking for a piece of advice on how to deal with the new status in the company and if you recommend any book to improve the leadership skills in a company.

Comment: "he did not want to do it as he was thinking that in the future it could be used." Don't you guys use version control? If he needs that code again, he can just recover it. Deleting it was the right move.

Comment: Yes, we use Git. I told that actually. @StephanBranczyk

Comment: I recommend this book by Manuel J. Smith on assertiveness training: https://www.amazon.com/When-Say-No-Feel-Guilty/dp/0553263900 But do not try to judge that book by its title, read its actual customer reviews. That book changed my life.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk it seems pretty good. I am going to buy it. Thanks!

Comment: When you gave your reason for deleting it, did the co-worker have an answer to that and did you actively listen to it?

Comment: Hi @Helena, I was listening to him. The main point for him is that the library was more complete in that way, but the thing is that we are not building a library for clients. I agreed that is okay if we have to ship to someone else. But in our case, as there is no need, we have to delete and just keep the necessary code. No more, no less. Also, as we are working in a medical device environment is crucial to just have the necessary code and tests for it. But still, he wanted to have the object for completeness, even if the code is not going to use ever. At least in a near future.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk theoretically that is an argument, but even if version control is used, the history is not always kept depending on practice. At the two companies where I worked, the feature/bugfix branches were deleted from the server to remove clutter. And on my current team, not only are we removing the branches, we're also squashing the branches.

Comment: @StephanBranczyk even if the branches are kept, then there is the question: how do you find the code once it is deleted? It might be easy tomorrow, but 3 years down the line, good luck. This might be a good question for the Software Engineering SE.

Answer (score 3):

Been there, seen it, got the T-Shirt, and I'm usually the person on the other side telling my Manager why I think they are making a foolish decision.

So here's my perspective (which may or may not help guide your future interactions).

If I'm digging my heels in, I usually have a good reason to do so. In this case, the reason given was Future requirements - that's a good reason to keep it.

What are the reasons for not keeping it?

Cleanliness of code - It's an Aesthetic decision, not really a technical decision

Unused functionality could increase surface area for attack - This is a technical reason, it may not be relevant, but there's always a good argument that anything not necessary is a potential vulnerability.

Space - This is less of a biggy than it used to be when storage was expensive, but still bloated code is bloated.

I'm the new Manager and need to stamp my Authoritaaaaa here - That's potentially how he's viewing it.

However, what you could do is what I've called 'The Curved Fence' approach. So you talk with the employee, you aren't saying you want them to delete the code, you want to know how it will be used in the future, is it needed now? is it something that we could retain in a development build and maybe add to sprint to implement the functionality it will be needed for?

Instead of putting up a hard wall for them to butt their head against, your giving them a curve to which they can slide along (topical NASCAR reference...) to eventually reach the desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

Look for courses and videos on soft skills. Being a good manager isn't necessarily about being the best technical person. You're there to inspire, to show good practice (like remove cruft from code if it isn't needed), and to remove any blockages so your team can perform effectively.

Sometimes you're a meat barrier, preventing the rest of the organization from disturbing your team. Sometimes you're the person who tells someone to go home for the day because they have a situation in their personal life that they need to address immediately. Sometimes you're the person who has to remove someone from the team permanently because they're not performing.

One thing you are not, is a friend or a workmate. Don't expect to be friends with everyone who works for you. Occasionally (not too often), you need to sternly say, "we're doing it this way". Someone has to take decisions, and you're the one getting the big bucks for doing just that.

In all conversations, however, remember that it's a person you're talking to, not a dog. Help them to work at their best, and be an enabler for the team, not a blocker.

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment! It's inspiring.

Answer (score 1):

I think the key(s) to being a good manager (from the IC perspective) is two-fold: empathy and servant-leadership.  Empathy is key for the workplace at any level or role but leading with empathy is how that gets socialized the best.  The worst thing that could happen is losing the good will of your direct reports if you come off as inauthentic with your empathy, so if there is any doubt about it maybe a book would be good here.

[Servant-leadership](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Servant_leadership) is crucial, as well.  So many issues at work arise from the inability of management to make work easier, especially when the opposite occurs and they end up making work harder.  My coworker friends in the past have referred to it as "seagulling" where managers will swoop in at the worst moment to steal, create unneccesary noise or worse, just crap on your work.  Your job is going to be mostly about creating harmony now, don't worry about your technical skills as I'm sure you'll be appreciating where you are at more as time goes on and you manage more junior developers.

Answer (score 0):

You are being paid to lead, so that is what you must do. Whilst you should make every effort to make well-balanced decisions, sooner or later someone has to decide what will & will not be done, and that person is you.

Soft-management schemes such as servant-leadership are fine, so long as everyone respects your role as a decision-maker, but unfortunately some of your team could take it as an indication of indecisiveness or weakness, and just ignore what you say, rendering your role redundant.

So you need to cultivate a 'firm but fair' persona, carefully considering the input from all quarters, but making it crystal clear that the final decision is yours (within the scope set by your manager). Providing everyone can see the rationale of your decisions, they should respect them, even if they think you might be wrong.